# Is there any solution that this computer recognize the list but not as a integer?

Tags: python, list, integer, traceback

Target: finding the best scorer on each subjects separately. The scores are received throughout int(input()).

Example
Math: [0 20 30 40 50 ] Output: "Best Score: 50"

English: [0 40 50 80 90 ] Output: "Best Score: 80"

Science: [0 90 78 90 97 ] Output: "Best Score: 97"

Problem: Even when I used either copy() or list[:], the computer still recognizes the copied code as a integer object, not as a list.

Input code: Works completely right

The code which is the problem:

```
   subject_score = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   a, b, c = subject_score[:]
   i = 0
   for subject in midterm_score:
       for i in range(0, len(subject_score) - 1):
           a[i] = midterm_score[0][i]
           b[i] = midterm_score[1][i]
           c[i] = midterm_score[2][i]
       minscore1 = a[0]
       for i in range(1, len(subject_score) - 1):
           if minscore1 < a[i]:
               minscore1 = a[i]
       minscore2 = b[0]
       for i in range(1, len(subject_score) - 1):
           if minscore2 < b[i]:
               minscore2 = b[i]
       minscore3 = c[0]
       for i in range(1, len(subject_score) - 1):
           if minscore3 < c[i]:
               minscore3 = c[i]
   print(a, b, c)
   print("Math:"+ minscore1)
   print("English:" + minscore2)
   print("Science:"+ minscore3)
```

Where problem occurs:

```
    subject_score = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    a, b, c = subject_score[:]
```

The Coder's Ability: Noob

Answerer: Will have a great day

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want the variables a, b and c to contain? `[0,0,0,0,0]`?

Comment: First, You should get an valueError when assigning subject_score to a, b and c. If you want to assign subject_score to a, b and c so that a, b and c become list, you have to do it separately. something like a = score[:];b = score[:];c=score[:]

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is python uses assignment unpacking.

```
your_list = [0,1,2]
a, b, c = your_list
```

In this example the variables will not be the same as the list, but the elements of the list will be unpacked. This will actually be the result:

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 2
```

If you want to make each variable to be the same as `your_list`, you can do this:

```
a = your_list
b = your_list 
c = your_list
```

Or you can do this:

```
a, b, c = [your_list for i in range(x)]
```

Remember to substitube `x` for the amount of variables you want